# Format float to decimals (ones, tens, hundreds ...)

Tags: python, string

In the `round()` function it is possible to go from a float to i.e. a number rounded to the ten-spot:

`round(123.2,-1)` yields 120

or

`round(123,2,0)` yields 123

Is there a way to do the same thing using format?

Like: `"{:.-1f}".format(123.2) = "120"`

or in other notation?

```
format(123.2,.-1f)="120"
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `round` to get the number you want and display that?

Comment: Thats a solution, but isnt possible to use the format function directly?

Comment: No, you can't, just round the number first. (You can in a `f'...'` string because that accepts expressions).

Comment: No you can't. In the same way that you can not format a string with `round()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Formatting specifies the *width* of the output (where number of digits after the decimal is really a width adjustment), where rounding is only used to achieve the right width.

Just round first, then format the rounded result.

In Python 3.6 and newer, you can put the rounding expression in an f-string, of course:

```
f'Result: {round(123.2, -1)}'
```